# Link to Google Play from Facebook - bypass internal browser

Tags: android, facebook, google-play

I'm trying to link from Facebook pages and posts directly to my app. I want the link to open in the Google Play application on Android devices.

Ever since Facebook started using an internal browser for links, links to `https://play.google.com/details?id=` and `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=` from Facebook do not trigger the Play application, and are handled by the internal browser.

How can I bypass the internal browser and cause the Play application to catch the URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @k-m-Śliwiński has atated, we need to use the `market://` scheme to fire up Play.
This is problematic for several reasons:

1. Facebook does not recognize this as a link.
2. URL shortening and redirection services do not recognize this as a link, so a device specific link (via smarturl.it for example) can not be issues.
3. The rare URL shortening services that do allow this are considered dangerous by Facebook and are blocked by it.

I ended up setting up a redirect (301) HTML webpage, storing it on one of my servers and creating a valid `http://` URL pointing to it.

I've used the [301 Redirect Code Generator](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/redirect-generator.htm) in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would need to use the following protocol:

```
market://details?id=PACKAGE_NAME
```

But Facebook doesn't recognize this as a valid link. Only thing that comes to my mind is placing the above link behind an URL redirecting service. The problem is that most of these services don't allow to shorten links that do not begin with `http`. I've found a service that allows for custom protocols in the link, it's: `http://bit.do/`

Of course you could also create your own redirecting website if you have a place to host it.